# Keeps track of files in eclipse, who made changes on which branch

Tags: eclipse, git, mercurial, bitbucket, tortoisehg

Keeps track of files in eclipse, who made changes on which branch
Hello Guys, I am using BitBucket for project management, and i Create different branches as per features. Multiple teams works on their own branches and some time multiple teams make changes in same file. 

So at the time of release I have to merge all the created branches in one major branch, but at time of merge i get a lot of merge conflicts, 
**So basically what i want, when developer going to make changes in any file, dev will get to know all submitted changes in another branches for this same file, (where dev going to make changes),** So he or she will know the possible scenarios.

Comment: You're probably going to need a server side Git hook, with a lengthy script.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to ask for a developer to [rebase his/her own branch](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) on top of the main branch first.

Then you can merge that branch easily enough.

That way:

- if there are any conflicts, they are detected and resolve by the developer (who knows best how to resolve it)
- each merge is a trivial one.

Comment: Thank, I will try to write the script

Comment: @DupinderSingh OK. So 10 moths later, the issue is still relevant, I suppose?

Comment: Now i got time for this, so I am trying to find the old code and questions, that i asked, BTW Thanks.